# How can I retrieve data from Firestore to my list

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, future

```
class Profile {

  final List<String> photos;
  final String name;
  ......

  Profile({
    this.photos,
    this.name,
    ......
  });

}

final List<Profile> demoProfiles = [
  Profile (
    photos: [
      "https:...",

    ],
    name: "Fatih",
    age: 22,
    distance: 4,
    education: "Hacettepe University"
  ),
  Profile (
    photos: [
       "https:...",
       "https:...",

    ],
    name: "Elysium",
    age: 23,
    distance: 2,
    bio: "Test bio"
  )
];
```

How can I retrieve data from Firestore and then update my List demoProfiles and the use it at my main_controller.dart? I am really new to flutter , can anyone one help me ?Thank you .

```
final MatchEngine matchEngine = MatchEngine (
    matches:demoProfiles.map((Profile profile) => Match(profile: profile)).toList()
  );
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried to change my main_controller.dart to the above screenshot but it returned the error : type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Profile>

Comment: Can you receive the data from firebase or not ?

Comment: yes , I tried to print out the data and it 's okay

Comment: So now what's the problem?

Comment: it returned an error :A value of type 'Future<List<Profile>>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<Profile>'.and if I navigate between other pages and main controller , it returned error:NoSuchMethodError: The method 'map' was called on null

Comment: You can't assign directly to that because both types are different that's why you getting that error

Comment: how can I fix this error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214421/discussion-between-nikunj-kumbhani-and-ziv-cheung).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it like below please?

```
Future<Profile> fetchData() async {...}
```

Comment: Well, I have a solution for you..may be it's not an efficient way...but.. hopefully it will work, most probably,..and here's my solution..just declare demoProfiles as `var`..like this..```var demoProfiles = fetch data();``` do reply if it worked for you..

Comment: Can you please try `list.add(doc.data)` instead of  `new Profile(...) `  if it's not work for you try  `list = querySnapshot.documents` after  `.documents; ` instead of using forEach method.

Answer (score 0):

**You can do it like this**

```
List<Profile> demoProfiles = [];

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  loadDataMethod();
}

void loadDataMethod() async {
  demoProfiles = await fetchData();
  setState(() {});
}


Future<List<Profile>> fetchData() async {
  List<Profile> list;
  // Fetch Data Logic
  return list;
}
```

**OR like this**

```
List<Profile> demoProfiles = fetchData() as List<Profile>;
```

Comment: it returned the error : List<Profile> demoProfiles
package:flutter_chat_demo/src/scenes/in/main_controller.dart

Only static members can be accessed in initializers.

Comment: sorry for the late reply , I updated the errors and the match engine . please take a look

Comment: @ZivCheung Remove static keyword